# Visual Studio 2015 Profiler (vsperf.exe) does NOT work without admin rights

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiler, admin-rights

I have installed Visual Studio 2015, and I'm using a user account WITHOUT admin rights - but when I try to start the profiler (vsPerf.exe or vsStandardCollector.exe) through the Visual Studios menu (Analyze --> Performance and Diagnostics menu) it requires admin rights and prompts for admin user to enter user and password.

I have followed Microsofts own description (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182387.aspx), but without luck - it still prompts for admin user.

Does anyone know how to run the Profiler through Visual Studio, using a user account without admin rights?